# 1D Marginals of Permutahedron?

Tags: probability-theory, convex-geometry

For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the *permutahedron* is the convex polytope (for $S_n$ the symmetric group).
$$
P_n = \mathsf{conv}(\sigma((1,2,\dots,n)) \mid \sigma\in S_n\}
$$
i.e. it is given by the convex hull of all permutations of some fixed coordinate vector $(1,2,\dots,n)$.

For a uniform random variable $U\sim \mathsf{Unif}(P_n)$, what is known about the 1-dimensional marginals of $P_n$?
By this, I mean the distribution induced by projecting $P_n$ onto any particular coordinate axis.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve your question for $n=3$ ?

Comment: I haven't yet. I do not anticipate the problem to be difficult to solve, but if it has been worked out somewhere before it seems somewhat better to cite previous work.

Comment: There is maybe a connection with the so-called "box splines". See this [on-line document](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233968739_Topics_in_Hyperplane_Arrangements_Polytopes_and_Box-Splines)